# iOS Mapkit - dequeueReusableAnnotationView with Interface Builder XIB

Tags: ios, interface, mapkit, xib, builder

Is there a way to create a custom annotation view in the interface builder (XIB), but also make use of MapKit's `dequeueReusableAnnotationView` method?

The use of `dequeueReusableAnnotationView` seems to imply that we are just using a subclass of MKAnnotationView where you can draw all subviews programmatically.

I am properly registering my custom AnnotationViews via the `MapView.register()` method

I'm struggling to find a way to use `dequeueReusableAnnotationView` and the XIB for the custom view.

Comment: Have you created a `class` file for the view you have created in interface builder and then linked them in the identity inspector?

Comment: @magnas, yes I have done that. Doing that does not automatically generate a view that has what the XIB looks like. It all depends on how the object is instantiated. I actually ended up figuring this out. If anyone wants to know how, please let me know.